# Assign a class instance to a static member variable of another class

Tags: php, oop

First of all I thought python was madness but it looks like php is the wild west.

```php
<?php
use Creations\Robot;

class RoboticAnimal extends Robot {
  use Creations\AnimalMixin;

  public function __construct ($speed, $name, $band, $wheels, $age, $weight, $blood_type) {
    parent::__construct($name, $band, $wheels);
    $this->__constructAnimal(now(), $age, $weight, $blood_type);
    $this->speed = $speed;
  }

  // !! Don't forget to override these on you object that extends RoboticAnimal !!
  // There should be a preprocces step to allow this:
  //   public static $foo = new AnimalTraits("Slug", 69, 420, 9001);
  public static $foo = [
     "AnimalType": "Slug",
     "MaxAmount": 69,
     "MatingSpeed": 420,
     "PowerLevel": 9001
  ];

  public static $robotTraits = [ "Immortal": true ]; 

  ...
}
```

All the animals need to have these 4 parameters `AnimalType` `MaxAmount` `MatingSpeed` `PowerLevel`. So to manage these 4 values we created an `AnimalTraits` object because OOP is good, however we cant assign these animal traits instance to our class as seen in the code snippit (and comments).

**Is there away to assign an object instance of class to a static member field of a different class? (see comments of static member in code)**
It seems like this should be possible considering we assign the array, and thats the **OOP Way**

Comment: There's a lot of stuff here, but it seems like you're just asking how to initialize a static property to something that isn't a constant. Is that right?

Comment: The first line: `use /Creations/Robot;` should throw a syntax error. The namespace delimiter in PHP is backslash: `use Creations\Robot;` (the first slash isn't necessary with `use` statements). The same goes for the `use` statement for the trait inside the class.

Comment: Your declaration of `$foo` is also broken, not proper syntax for an associative array. Do yourself a favour and get a decent IDE, your learning curve will be massively reduced.